# Сервер не понимает конкретные значения, отправленные клиентом

Tags: javascript, сервер

Почему сервер не воспринимает конкретные значения, отправленных с клавиатуры?

В консоли браузера выводятся значения, например: w, s, d, a

В консоли же сервера эти значения выводятся так: [object KeyboardEvent], [object KeyboardEvent], [object KeyboardEvent], [object KeyboardEvent]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы сервер воспринимал именно те значения, которые были отправлены ему клиентом с клавиатуры?

JS:

```
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    ws.send(event);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
    ws.send(event.key);
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо